# create a field in drupal to select related content based on selected terms

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

I have a content type news article. this content type has a term reference fields. which allow to select multiple terms based on particular taxonomy.

I want to create another fields related content type with multi choice.And whenever a term is selected all the nodes of that terms should be listed as choice in related content type fields.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't have it out of the box. Instead, create your fields as you described and then create a view which will take content types and taxonomy terms as contextual parameter. You may need a bit of code to get selected content types and taxonomy terms and "prepare" them to be in correct format to pass them to that view.

And you can use:

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7.x-3.x

or

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7.x-3.x

to call your view from code and pass selected parameters to it.